# How to fill LinearLayout with FrameLayout squares?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I'm doing a chess game where I have:

```
scrollView
    -LinearLayout(Vertical)
        -LinearLayout(horizontal)*8
            -FrameLayout(with android:background=@color/black or white resource)*8
```

I was using `ImageView` to make the chessboard and then I switched to `FrameLayout` background with a black or white image file and now I'm using resources to set the colors, but I have a problem. I'm unable to keep the squares of the chessboard (I want them to adjust size to the phone screen) and I was able to do that by setting "adjust view bounds" on 1ImageView1 or just by setting the 1framelayout1 background image. How can I keep the squares using resource colors?

Comment: Maybe grid view will be better in this case?

Comment: would gridview resize to screen size?

Comment: i did a little search and i found out GrivView uses ListAdapter i just want to move ImageView from framelayout to framelayout